# Azure Functions Linux upgrading from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6 doesn't upgrade LinuxFXVersion

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I have upgraded my Azure functions code to .NET 6 and also using Azure Functions version 4.0 using Azure CLI with the `az functionapp config appsettings set --settings FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION=~4 -g <resource Group> -n <functionname>`

When I check Func runs on version 4.3.2.2 and FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION in the settings is displayed as 4 but I see warning as "Your app is pinned to an unsupported runtime version for 'dotnet'. For better performance, we recommend using one of our supported versions instead: ~3.". Displayed Runtime version as "custom" also.

[image]

This is probably related to LinuxFXversion still being 3.1. Why doest it remain at 3.1? How to upgrade it?

[image]

using `az functionapp config set --name <Function name> --resource-group <resource group> --linux-fx-version '"DotNet|6.0"'`

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config?view=azure-cli-latest) is pretty poor.

Doesnt work as well.

EDIT: I set debug parameter and Azure CLI is showing me as

> cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The
> parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid
> value.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"The parameter
> LinuxFxVersion has an invalid
> value."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"ExtendedCode":"01007","MessageTemplate":"The
> parameter {0} has an invalid
> value.","Parameters":["LinuxFxVersion"],"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The
> parameter LinuxFxVersion has an invalid value."}}],"Innererror":null}
> cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:

Answer (score 0):

Try using it in this way "DOTNET-6.0"

```
az functionapp config set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --linux-fx-version "DOTNET-6.0"
```

Comment: Hello @apoorvpatil, we tried on your command too - it is not working https://i.imgur.com/sxSpocJ.png . Did you tried to reproduce the same?

Comment: yes i had the same error on my code. but now its working fine by the above method that i have pasted

Comment: could you please paste the screenshot of output of that command execution

Comment: 2022-06-03T11:25:43.9706969Z   "javaContainer": null,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9707365Z   "javaContainerVersion": null,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9707691Z   "javaVersion": null,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9708079Z   "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": null,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9708503Z   "kind": null,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9708801Z   "limits": null,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9709142Z   "linuxFxVersion": "DOTNET-6.0",
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9709587Z   "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9709974Z   "localMySqlEnabled": false,
2022-06-03T11:25:43.9710321Z   "location": "UK South",

Comment: added the image here. that should help i think. 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh6K0.png

Comment: Try using powershell instead of bash

Answer (score 0):

Just want to answer my own question. very interesting but MS documentation is misleading. This command is working in Powershell but not in Cmd. Anyone looking for a solution for this. try in powershell, specifcally Developer Powershell for VS 2019/2022

```
az functionapp config set --name AppName --resource-group ResournceName --linux-fx-version '"DOTNET|6.0"'
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are (powershell)

```
Update-AzFunctionAppSetting -AppSetting @{"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" = "~4"} -Name <NAME> -ResourceGroupName <RSG> -Force

Set-AzWebApp -NetFrameworkVersion v6.0 -Name <NAME> -Resource
```

GroupName